# Spark - creating schema programmatically with different data types

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset consisting of 7-8 fields which are of type String, Int & Float.

Am trying to create Schema by Programmatic approach by using this :

```
val schema = StructType(header.split(",").map(column => StructField(column, StringType, true)))
```

And Then mapping it to Row type like :

```
val dataRdd = datafile.filter(x => x!=header).map(x => x.split(",")).map(col => Row(col(0).trim, col(1).toInt, col(2).toFloat, col(3), col(4) ,col(5), col(6), col(7), col(8)))
```

But after creating DataFrame when i use DF.show() it gives error for the Integer field.

So how to create such schema where we have multiple data type in the dataset

Answer (score 5):

The problem you have in your code is that you are assigning all the fields as StringType.

Assuming that in the header you have only the name of the fields, then you can't guess the type.

Let's assume that the header string is like this

```
val header = "field1:Int,field2:Double,field3:String"
```

Then the code should be

```
def inferType(field: String) = field.split(":")(1) match {
   case "Int" => IntegerType
   case "Double" => DoubleType
   case "String" => StringType
   case _ => StringType
}

val schema = StructType(header.split(",").map(column => StructField(column, inferType(column), true)))
```

For the header string example you get

```
root
 |-- field1:Int: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- field2:Double: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field3:String: string (nullable = true)
```

On the other hand. If what you need it's a data frame from text, I would suggest that you create the DataFrame directly from the file itself. It's pointless to create it from an RDD.

```
val fileReader = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferschema", "true")
  .option("delimiter", ",")

val df = fileReader.load(PATH_TO_FILE)
```

Comment: But the Header String is not like this and data is like

`dfs8768768, 65, 76.34, 234, dfgdg, 34.65
dfs8768768, 65, 76.34, 234, dfgdg, 34.65`

Comment: Then the it's impossible to know from the header the type of the data, as it's not provided.

Comment: This is the exact data with header :

`Auctioned,bid,bidtime,bidder,bidderrate,openbid,price,item,daystolive
8213034715,15,12.373,baman,3,12,20,book1,5
8213034725,65,21.33,thmpu,2,64,75,watch1,9
8213034735,85,23.3,lovekush,4,45,90,remote1,10
8213034745,115,44.44,jaipanee,3,111,130,s3phone,4`

Comment: Do you realize that spark can't guess the type of the columns from the header? Check the link on my updated answer. You would rather consider creating your dataframe directly from the data, without creating an rdd. You can do that by instantiating a spark.reader.

Comment: Well thanks for replying elghoto. But i tried and i was to solve this. As i am not trying a work-around i wanted to do it from RDD to DF only

Answer (score 2):

Defining the Structure Type first :

```
val schema1 = StructType(Array(
  StructField("AcutionId", StringType, true),
  StructField("Bid", IntegerType, false),
  StructField("BidTime", FloatType, false),
  StructField("Bidder", StringType, true),
  StructField("BidderRate", FloatType, false),
  StructField("OpenBid", FloatType, false),
  StructField("Price", FloatType, false),
  StructField("Item", StringType, true),
  StructField("DaystoLive", IntegerType, false)
))
```

Then specifying each column that is going to b present inside a Row by converting it to specific types:

```
val dataRdd = datafile.filter(x => x!=header).map(x => x.split(","))
  .map(col => Row(
    col(0).trim,
    col(1).trim.toInt,
    col(2).trim.toFloat,
    col(3).trim,
    col(4).trim.toFloat,
    col(5).trim.toFloat,
    col(6).trim.toFloat,
    col(7).trim,
    col(8).trim.toInt)
  )
```

Then applying the Schema to the RDD

```
val auctionDF = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(dataRdd,schema1)
```

Comment: How do we have different datatypes for a same filed in Struct.